# Removing merge with ancestor

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a mercurial repo of the followng form:

```
... 27-28----------------------38-39 ... tip
         \__ 29 __ ... __ 37__/
```

as you can see, I have accidently merged 37 into 28, creating 38. How can I fix this, so that I get a simple linear history like the follwing:

```
... 27-28-29-...-37-39-...tip
```

Comment: Is your merge public, i.e. have you pushed it out? Once a change is public, it is immutable, and can't be changed or moved. Also, why do you want a linear history? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: No, it is not yet published. There is no strong reason why I need it. I was just curious about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this.  You could probably use the `convert` extension to rebuild the repository with that history using the `--branch-map` argument and manually stitching it together as you'd like, but it'll invalidate all existing clones, change the hashes, and be a pain to do.  Don't fetishize a linear history -- anonymous branches and merges are part of a normal DVCS workflow.  Embrace it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not pushed yet, the easiest is to `rebase` 39 (and descendants) on top of 37, and simply `strip` changeset 38.

You'll get your linear history, but as @Ry4an said, "embrace" the fact that your history will not be linear, otherwise it will just make you unhappy...